# What is the best-practice for having environment-specific Puppet scripts?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I need to remove a few files when in development environment (for example when using Vagrant) but not in production. I want to disable `firewalld` when in development, but not in production. I would like to disable `selinux` whenon development, but not on production.

What is the best practice for doing these? I would like to use my puppet scripts both on development environments (with Vagrant) and on production.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good practice to have scripts specific to an environment. Instead you should have scripts which will behave differently based on environment. Let me show you how; there are two steps you will need to do for this to work:

1. Define environments

You will have to define environments - I would suggest directory based environments (Because config based environment support will be dropped eventually). How to setup environments is an intimate topic and I suggest you check out the [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/environments.html)

2. Use environments in your code

Let's say you have defined environments such as dev, qa, uat, prod etc. You can get the name of current environment by using `$environment` variable. Your manifests should leverage the environment variable to decide weather a firewall should be enabled/disabled etc. For example:

(Modified based on Felix's comment, thanks @Felix)

```
include profile::webserver
if $environment != 'dev'
    include profile::firewall
```

In above piece of code if the `$environment` does not match to "dev" only then the firewall role is applied!

Comment: Basically yes, although according to the Roles and Profiles pattern, `webserver` and `firewall` should be **profiles** rather than roles. You want `webserver` in either case, so the structure would be `include profile::webserver` and `if $environment != 'dev' { include profile::firewall }`.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the note - you have a valid point. BTW Is there a reference of patterns for Puppet?

Comment: I don't think there is. Aside from the [Best Practices](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/best_practices.html), Roles and Profiles is pretty much the only important pattern that I am aware of.

Comment: Is this for Enterprise Puppet?

Comment: Based on this link https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/environments_creating.html I think they are available in Puppet Open Source but PE has additional configuration requirements. Try creating one - it is fairly simple.